# Error in knn - 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r

I am using KNN from 'class' package. I have the 'features' dataframe with multiple columns. Below is my code:

In this, my training set and my test set are the same and I randomly select 100% of data:

```
kn_data <- sample(1:nrow(features), size=nrow(features)*1, replace = FALSE)

train_kn_data <- features[kn_data,]
test_kn_data <- features[kn_data, ]
```

Then I create he labels to compare the final outcome with. Over here, I use four individual columns from the 'features' dataframe. The 'features' dataframe originally has '18' columns.

```
train_labels_kn_data <- as.data.frame(features[kn_data, c("label", "nr_pix", "aspect_ratio",
                                                  "rows_with_1", "cols_with_1")])

test_labels_kn_data <- as.data.frame(features[kn_data, c("label", "nr_pix", "aspect_ratio",
                                                 "rows_with_1", "cols_with_1")])
```

In the above, only 'label' column has alphabetical values. Other three columns have numerical values.

Then I run knn:

```
knn_1 <- knn(train = train_kn_data, test = test_kn_data, cl = train_labels_kn_data, k = 1)
```

On running that, I encounter this error:

```
Error in knn(train = train_kn_data, test = test_kn_data, cl = train_labels_kn_data,  : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

I checked the number of rows of train_kn_data and train_labels_kn_data. They're both the same.

How do I fix this error then and what is meant by having different lengths? Is it because of different number of columns?

Comment: Please check out this minimalist code for knn: https://github.com/sjhalayka/xor_dataframe_r/blob/main/iris.r

Comment: @shawn_halayka Thank you but I'm trying to figure out the issue in my code too so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: According the to the manual page, `cl` is a "factor of true classifications of training set". You are passing multiple columns. Since a data frame in R is a list, the length of the data frame is the number of columns, not the number of rows.